# CSS floats are causing layout issues

Tags: html, css

When I use the following code, the last div overlaps the floated content:

```
<div style="width:50%;float:left;">test</div>
<div style="width:50%;float:left;">test</div>
<div style="background:red;">test</div>
```

The common fix is to do this:

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;">
<div style="width:50%;float:left;">test</div>
<div style="width:50%;float:left;">test</div>
</div>
<div style="background:red;">test</div>
```

However, in my case, I cannot add in an extra element. Is there another workaround for this?

**Edit:**
clear:both; fixed the overlapping issue, but there's a margin on the last div, so it's something like this:

```
<div style="width:50%;float:left;">test</div>
<div style="width:50%;float:left;">test</div>
<div style="background:red;clear:both;margin-top:50px;">test</div>
```

And now the new problem is that the margin isn't showing up.

Comment: You have two divs each at 50% floating left.  They are going to fill the full width of the outer container, forcing a wrap.  Is the problem that you don't want the wrap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply clear the floats...

```
<div style="background:red;clear: both;">test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `clear` property on your last `<div>` to `left` or `both`:

```
<div style="background: red; clear: left;">test</div>
```

Edit: As for the margin, you can do some relative positioning:

```
<div style="background: red; clear: left; margin-bottom: 50px; position: relative; top: 50px;">test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<div style="width:50%;float:left;">test</div>
<div style="width:50%;float:left;">test</div>
<div style="background:red;clear:left;">test</div>
```

EDIT. To get the margin-top, add margin bottom to the floated elements

```
<div style="width:50%;float:left;margin-bottom:50px;">test</div>
<div style="width:50%;float:left;margin-bottom:50px;">test</div>
<div style="background:red;clear:both;">test</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

There's no need to use floats here. Make the first two elements `inline-block` elements, and the third element a `block`-level element.

HTML:

```
<div class="inline-block">
    Test
</div><div class="inline-block">
    Test
</div>

<div class="block">Test</div>
```

*Note that `</div><div class="inline-block">` are touching. Because these two element are inline-block elements, any space in the markup will produce space in the presentation.*

CSS:

```
.inline-block { 
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block; }
.block { margin: 50px 0 0; }
```

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/eGPWt/